# Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.conn" is null

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I don't know why connection is not establishing. I tried by restarting tomcat server multiple times, but same error is raised.
Actually I checked if init() method is called, the method was not called even for multiple times restarting server.
-added all jar files and all libraries required

```
package login_registration;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;


public class RegisterUser extends GenericServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Connection conn=null;
    public RegisterUser() {
        super();
    }
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "c##jdbc_practice",
                    "Oracle123");
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
        String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
        String password=request.getParameter("pwd");
        try {
            PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into userinfo values(?,?,?,?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, fname);
            pstmt.setString(2,lname);
            pstmt.setString(3, uname);
            pstmt.setString(4, password);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
            pw.println("<html><head>");
            pw.println("<body><h1>registed</hi</body>");
            pw.print("</head></html>");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Though you can load a connection per servlet, it's strongly advised you use a connection pool. That's already available in Tomcat for free. Set the JDBC Datasource in the JNDI directory (using the context.xml file) and then get it from there while in the servlet.

Comment: Where does `e.printStackTrace()` (from `init()`) end up? What does it contain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using deplorably bad exception handling.

```
try {
 stuff();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is the equivalent of: If bad things happen, shrug and just keep doing the motions even though they are now pointless, like a clichéd silly robot in an old cartoon. A person on a bike when the chain comes off that just madly pedals onwards, oblivious to the notion that the pedal no longer does anything.

The correct approach is obviously to handle it properly, if you can. For the vast majority of exceptions, there's nothing you can do about it. In that case, your method should throw it onwards (`void foo() throws SQLException`). If that too is not possible:

```
try {
  stuff();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);
}
```

What's happening here is that the connection fails, but your code just prints something and keeps going, resulting in `con` being `null`, causing *more* errors. The result is a ton of errors, all of them irrelevant, except the first one.

What's the *actual* problem? You didn't paste that part. But the exception will tell you. Probably wrong user/pass, or the mysql server isn't accepting TCP/IP based connections, or the mysql server isn't on, or any of a million other things it could be. That's why you want the error.